# Getting EmptyDataFrame Error from Facebook Ads Report URL in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, facebook, csv, url

I am using the pandas 'read_csv' method to read a Facebook URL which links to an Ads Report CSV file - this link automatically downloads a CSV when pasted in the browser. Normally I am able to pass a URL like this directly into pandas.read_csv() and get out a dataframe, but current I'm getting an 'EmptyDataError: No columns to parse from file' from this link.

I understand an alternative to getting this data would be accessing the Facebook Graph API, but right now being able to access this URL directly via some Python or other code would be most useful for setting up my Ads Reporting process. The code looks something like the below:

`ads_report = pd.read_csv('https://www.facebook.com/ads/report_builder/past_report/download_report/?report_run_id=123456789101112&export_format=csv&source=email')`

I'd expect the output of to be a regular dataframe, but currently I'm receiving this error:
`EmptyDataError: No columns to parse from file`

Comment: You could download it with your browser and use `pd.read_csv('/local/path/to_csv')` to load it...

Comment: I want to avoid downloading anything through the browser - this script will ideally pull a csv from a daily email, load and process on a daily basis, without me having to click or download anything manually.